# Java - Space complexity of recursion with lists

Tags: java, recursion, space-complexity

I believe the space complexity is O(n) here, but I'm also storing everything in the lists, so I'm not sure.

I believe it is only O(n) because of the recursions, but because I'm storing everything in lists, maybe this requires more space?

**The algorithm just shows the right side view of the binary tree, so if there root = 5, root.left = 3, root.right = 4. Then right side view will be just [5, 4]. If there was not a root.right, then right side view would be [5, 3]**

**What is the space complexity of this code?**

**Code:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestingJavaCode {

    public List<Integer> rightSideView(TreeNode root) {
        ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> leftS = new ArrayList<>();

        if (root == null) return res;

        res.add(root.val);
        leftS.add(root.val);

        if (root.right != null) {
            for (int i : rightSideView(root.right)) {
                res.add(i);
            }
        }

        if (root.left != null) {
            for (int j : rightSideView(root.left)) {
                leftS.add(j);
            }
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < leftS.size(); k++) {
            if (k > res.size() - 1) res.add(leftS.get(k));
        }

        return res;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestingJavaCode c = new TestingJavaCode();
        TreeNode s4 = new TreeNode(1);
        s4.left = new TreeNode(2);
        s4.right = new TreeNode(3);
        s4.left.left = new TreeNode(4);
        s4.left.right = new TreeNode(5);
        // [1, 3, 5]
        System.out.println(c.rightSideView(s4).toString());
    }

}

// Definition for a binary tree node.
class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;

    TreeNode(int x) {
        val = x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please state what the algorithm is supposed to do :)

Comment: Of course, added it now.

Comment: how `[1, 3]` would be an output? Did you mean `[5, 3]`?

Comment: `n log(n)` you have log(N) reduction call with for loop each

Comment: @A1m yes sorry, [5,3]. Made the change now

Comment: And what do you see as `n`? If `n` is the nodes in the tree, recursion will take `log(n)` space not `n`

Comment: I mean this `for (int k = 0; k < leftS.size(); k++)` gives `n`

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is O(n). Although storing data in lists instead of arrays will add a slight overhead, it will only be a small constant. This won't effect the space taken on a exponential scale.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you see `n` as number of nodes in that tree. In that case, the recursion will not take `O(n)` but the tree height as space. If you assume the tree is somewhat balanced the spacecomplexity of the recursion itself is `O(log n)` (but is `O(n)` for any tree - a list in the worst case).

But since you are storing every node in a list at the end the spacecomplexity degenerates to `O(n)` in all cases.

So yes. Spacecomplexity is `O(n)`, but your reasoning was not correct.

Comment: I would also note, that your algorithm has a few inefficient operations in it. You can optimize a lot there.